# adding a model to a view .net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to use two models in the same view (my view is strongly-typed to a model of mine and i  need to modify another model in the same view). Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ViewModel` which has  properties to represent your other `models` and pass an object of that to the `View`.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public Address Address {set;get;}
  public IList<Order> Orders {set;get;}

  public CustomerViewModel()
  {
     if(Address==null)
         Address=new Address();

     if(Orders ==null)
         Orders =new List<Order>();
  }
}

public class Address 
{
  public string AddressLine1 { set;get;} 
  //Other properties 
}

public class Order
{
  public int OrderID{ set;get;} 
  public int ItemID { set;get;}
  //Other properties 
}
```

Now in your Action method

```
public ActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
{
   CustomerViewModel objVM=repositary.GetCustomerFromId(id);
   objVm.Address=repositary.GetCustomerAddress(id);
   objVm.Orders=repositary.GetOrdersForCustomer(id);
   return View(objVM);
}
```

Your View will be typed to `CustomerViewModel`

```
@model CustomerViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
  <p>@Model.Address.AddressLine1</p>
  @foreach(var order in Model.Orders)
  {
    <p>@order.OrderID.ToString()</p>
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one model that combines the two models.  That's pretty common:

```
 public class CombinedModel
    {

        public ModelA MyFirstModel { get; set; }
        public ModelB MyOtherModel { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Also referred to as a "ViewModel"